# Create standalone text application from Python

Tags: python, c, python-standalone

I am developing a program to use as a pedagogical tool in my classroom. I'm writing currently writing it in Python, but I'm also open to solutions that would use C. I want to create a standalone application for Mac (.app file) for my program, but I only need text-based interaction with the users (i.e. just STDIN/STDOUT, and not a GUI). The majority of my students do not have python installed and have no experience with Terminal/shell scripting.

I tried using Platypus to create this application, but I get an error, as shown below.

[image]

I later realized that Platypus does not support prompts for user-input. Is there anything like Platypus that would also allow me to prompt users for input?

As I say, I'm also open to solutions to my problem which would involve transposing my Python code into C and going from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you have thinking about make a web app, in Google App Engine for example is very simple to deploy a Python based web app really fast, using [webapp2](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for example. And all your students could use your app online, [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/creating-guestbook) is a good getting started. But if you want maybe you could to build a command line app deployed in some server and your students could connect with ssh to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of systems your students have and it is highly unlikely that they will have similar kind of system. For least dependency i think you can use java to write your application. For java they just need to install **jdk** and can run your shared jar.